# Atualizar totalizador na actionbar ao excluir registro

Tags: android

Boa noite pessoal,
Estou desenvolvendo um app basico, e me deparei com alguns problemas ao atualizar totalizador de registros:

1. tenho uma activity contendo um RecyclerView listando os dados armazenados no banco de dados. Onde na actionbar eu adicionei um contador para informar a quantidade de registros cadastrados.
   Meu problema é que ao excluir um desses registros não estou conseguindo encontrar uma forma de atualizar esse contador na actionbar, se sair da activity e retornar recalcula correto.
2. Os dados cadastrados serão enviados para um webservice posteriormente, na activity de sincronismo tem um textview informando a quantidade de registros que serão sincronizados.
   No meu processo de envio utilizo uma asynctask para isso, se o envio do registro em questão receber um "OK" do webservice o mesmo é excluído do app. ao termino do sincronismo ficaria apenas os registros com algum erro ou falha acontece que esse contador também não estou conseguindo atualizar ao fim do processo. Preciso sair da activity e retornar para atualizar.

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Sem o código fica dificil, porém em ambos caso eu acredito que você pode passar um 'callback', que você pode chamar do seu RecyclerView e AsyncTask quando for necessário atualizar o contador.

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo do meu adapter do RecyclerView, da ação de exclusão

```
 holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Confirmação")
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete)
                    .setMessage("Tem certeza que deseja excluir este registro?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Excluir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            try {
                                Beneficiary.deleteAllBeneficiary(holder.id);
                                notifyItemChanged(position);
                                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
                                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                beneficiaryList.remove(position);

                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Registro Excluido! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                              
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Erro ao Excluir! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null)
                    .create()
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

Na minha activity para mostrar a quantidade de registro estou fazendo

List ben = Beneficiary.findAll();

```
    if (ben.size() > 1){
        setTitle("Beneficiários ("+ben.size()+")");
    }else{
        setTitle("Beneficiário ("+ben.size()+")");
    }
```

E o codigo dentro da activity de Sincronismo, onde chama a asynctask

```
  ben = Beneficiary.findAll();
  txtCountRegister.setText("Quantidade de registros: " + ben.size());
```

Ai abaixo disso tenho a ação do button que inicia o sincronismo.

```
 btnSync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ben.size() == 0) {
                Funcoes.Alert(getBaseContext(), "Nenhum registro para ser sincronizado");
            } else {
                BeneficiarySync beneficiarySync = new BeneficiarySync(SyncActivity.this);
                beneficiarySync.execute();
            }
        }
    });
```

Metodo doInBackgroud

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

    ErrorSync ClearTableError = new ErrorSync();
    ClearTableError.DeleteAllRegister();

    this.publishProgress("testConnection", "Testando conexão com a Internet");
    if (Funcoes.verificaConexao(context)) {
        if (VerifyUser()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ben.size(); i++) {
                message = "";
                int cont = i + 1;
                message += "Enviando Registro " + cont + " de " + ben.size() + "\n\n";
                Integer beneficiaryIdSuccess = SendBeneficiary(ben.get(i));


                beneficiary = Beneficiary.findByIdBeneficiary(ben.get(i).getId());
                beneficiary.setIdBeneficiaryWeb(beneficiaryIdSuccess);
                beneficiary.updateBeneficiary();

                if (beneficiaryIdSuccess > 0) {
                    if (ben.get(i).getMarital_status().equals("Casado") || ben.get(i).getMarital_status().equals("Amasiado")) {
                        SendSpouse(ben.get(i).getId(), beneficiaryIdSuccess);
                    }

                    sendCompositionFamily(ben.get(i).getId(), beneficiaryIdSuccess);
                    sendHouseInformation(ben.get(i).getId(), beneficiaryIdSuccess);
                    SendAttachment(ben.get(i).getId(), beneficiaryIdSuccess);
                    verifyRegister(ben.get(i).getId(), beneficiaryIdSuccess, i);
                }
            }
        } else {
            message = "Dados do Usuário na plataforma estão diferentes do Aplicativo. Verifique!!!";
            this.publishProgress("userInvalid", message);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            cancel(true);
        }
    } else {
        String msg = "Não foi possivel estabelecer uma conexão. Verifique sua conexão com a internet!!!";
        this.publishProgress("internetNo", msg);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        cancel(true);
    }

    List<ErrorSync> errorSyncsList = ErrorSync.findAllError();
    if (errorSyncsList.size() > 0) {
        this.publishProgress("ok", "Finalizado a Sincronização \n\n Quantidade de Erros: " + errorSyncsList.size());
    } else {
        this.publishProgress("ok", "Finalizado a Sincronização dos Dados");
    }
    return "Concluido";
}
```

Nesse cenário os registros que tiveram erros eles permanecem no app para correções, com isso o textview da activity tem que ser atualizado.